# Replace space character

Tags: c#, string, replace

I want to search in sql server where user can put keyword as `"java script" j2ee`. I want to replace every space before `j2ee` to `AND` , but not the space between `java` and `javascript`.

My code so far:

```
objCandidateShortInfo.strKeyWord =
    "(" + 
    txtAllKeywords.Value.Trim()
                        .ToUpper()
                        .Replace(",", " ")
                        .Replace("AND NOT", "")
                        .Replace("AND", "")
                        .Replace("OR", "")
                        .Replace(" ", " ")
                        .Replace(" ", " AND ")
    + ")";
```

It replaces all spaces with `AND`, but i dont want to replace spaces within the double quotes.

Could you suggest a solution to my problem?

Comment: Show you code for us..

Comment: Right now i am doing like objCandidateShortInfo.strKeyWord = "(" + txtAllKeywords.Value.Trim().ToUpper().Replace(",", " ").Replace("AND NOT", "").Replace("AND", "").Replace("OR", "").Replace("  ", " ").Replace(" ", " AND ") + ")"; so it replacing all space with "and" but i dont want to replace space within double quotes

Comment: Can you please add some more details on how you want to split? Which characters are the valid separators outside a block of quotes? An example for a complex input string and your expected output would help.

Comment: In textbox user can write any keyword but i need to put keyword under double quotes as it is but outside double quotes space should be replace with and . so that in sql server it will search using "contains"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this, you should split by the blanks and then assembly the parts again that are enclosed in quotation marks. The following sample shows an algorithm how to do this. I intentionally used an invalid input string with just an opening quotation mark at the end. The input string

> Test0 "Test1 Test2" "Test3 Test4

Leads to the following search string

> Test0 AND "Test1 Test2" AND "Test3 Test4"

The algorithm first splits by the blanks. It then runs over the resulting array and rebuilds the blocks that are enclosed in quotation marks. This is done in the `ParseString` method of the `Parser` class. After getting the parts, these are joined by `string.Join(" AND ", parts)` so that the search string is built.

```
void Main()
{
    var input = "Test0 \"Test1 Test2\" \"Test3 Test4";
    var parts = new Parser().ParseString(input);
    foreach(var part in parts)
        Console.WriteLine(part);
    var searchString = string.Join(" AND ", parts);
    Console.WriteLine("SearchString = " + searchString);
}

public class Parser
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ParseString(string input)
    {
        // Split by blanks
        var parts = input.Split(' ');
        var consolidatedParts = new List<string>();
        for(int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            var part = parts[i];
            // If part starts a block of quotes, add the following parts 
            // until either a closing quotation mark is found or the end 
            // is reached
            if (part.StartsWith("\""))
            {
                while (++i < parts.Length)
                {
                    part += " " + parts[i];
                    if (parts[i].EndsWith("\""))
                        break;
                }
                if (!part.EndsWith("\""))
                    part += "\"";
            }
            consolidatedParts.Add(part);
        }
        return consolidatedParts.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

In your code sample, you first remove some words from the input string (e.g. AND, AND NOT). You need to do this before splitting the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could first `split` the tokens and then `join` them with `AND`s:

```
objCandidateShortInfo.strKeyWord 
    = string.Join(" AND ", txtAllKeywords.Value.Split('"'));
```

Comment: thanks for reply but when i am putting two " i.e '""' its showing error message as too many characters in character literals

Comment: Thanks Dunken its working fine but if user will put keyword like '"asp .net" java javascript' then its not placing AND between java and javascript